# Three Fragments, interface on second Fragment requiring implementation on both Main and Second Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, communication

Taking the default 'Master/Detail' flow template in Eclipse, and adding a third Fragment (let's call it Edit, launched from the pre-existing Detail Fragment) and I'm now looking to open the Edit Fragment when a user clicks on an item in the Detail Fragment.

I've implemented an interface on the Detail fragment, however depending on whether the application is on a Tablet or Phone (dual-pane or not), the Iterface requires to be implemented by either the Detail Activity, or the Main Activity in order to function. I assume this is due to the way that the template implements opening of the Detail Fragment as an activity when the device is not in dual-pane mode.

Have I implemented this incorrectly, or is there a best practice that would allow me to unify the implementation of the interfaces into the main activity?

Here are some reduced snippets from the Master and Detail Fragments, showing the requirement for dual-implementation of the Detail Fragments interface.

Code for WaveListWactivity.java (first Fragment)

```
public class WaveListActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        WaveListFragment.Callbacks,WaveDetailFragment.Callbacks {
    private boolean mTwoPane;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wave_list);
        if (findViewById(R.id.wave_detail_container) != null) {
            mTwoPane = true;
            ((WaveListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.wave_list)).setActivateOnItemClick(true);
        }
    }

    //Interface from WaveListFragment
    @Override
    public void onWaveSelected(int id) {
        if (mTwoPane) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.wave_detail_container, new WaveDetailFragment()).commit();

        } else {
            Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, WaveDetailActivity.class);
            startActivity(detailIntent);
        }
    }

    //Interface from WaveDetailFragment
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(int id) {
        if (mTwoPane) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.wave_detail_container, new WaveEditFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();

        } else {
            Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, WaveDetailActivity.class);
            startActivity(detailIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

Code for WaveDetailActivity.java (second Fragment)

```
public class WaveDetailActivity extends FragmentActivity implements WaveDetailFragment.Callbacks {
    private boolean mTwoPane;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wave_detail);
        if (findViewById(R.id.wave_detail_container) != null) {
            mTwoPane = true;
        }

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.wave_detail_container, new WaveDetailFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    //Callback from WaveDetailFragment
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(int id) {
        if (mTwoPane) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.wave_detail_container, new WaveEditFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();

        } else {
            Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, WaveEditActivity.class);
            startActivity(detailIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be slightly confused as to the difference between `FragmentActivity`, `Fragments` and the callback interfaces that you need to implement on your `Activity`. From the looks of it, all the code snippets are `Activity` classes and *not* `Fragments`. I would expect a `Fragment` to look something like:

```
/** From http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html */

public class HeadlinesFragment extends ListFragment {
OnHeadlineSelectedListener mCallback;

// Container Activity must implement this interface
public interface OnHeadlineSelectedListener {
    public void onArticleSelected(int position);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
    // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
    try {
        mCallback = (OnHeadlineSelectedListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
    }
}

...
}
```

And then your `Activity`:

```
public static class MainActivity extends Activity
    implements HeadlinesFragment.OnHeadlineSelectedListener{
...

public void onArticleSelected(int position) {
    // The user selected the headline of an article from the HeadlinesFragment
    // Do something here to display that article
}
}
```

The overall 'flow' of this should be:

- Fragments act as blobs of UI code with callbacks for all the interesting stuff.
- Callbacks implemented by Activity.

The overall number of actions you can do depends on the fragments which depends on the size of your screen (so you may have 2 fragments which feed into a single Activity). The logic for determining whether to show one or two fragments should be done in the `Activity`.